# Parsing uniquely named nested JSON

Tags: c#, json, parsing

Preface:  I know of JSON.NET but I cannot use it (client machine).

I need to parse the JSON returned by http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD into 3 columns, date, currencyCode, and rate.  The issue is with the nested "rates" portion.  The currency code is the name of the first element which means I can't use "key" and "value" properties.  The only way I know of is to hardcode each possible currency code, which is what I have currently in the code below.  I want to be able to use key/value pairs to pull the code/rate simultaneously.

The JSON:

```
{"base":"USD",
 "date":"2016-07-12",
 "rates": {
     "AUD":1.3101,
     "BGN":1.7633,
     "BRL":3.2829,
     "CAD":1.3029,
     etc....}
 }
```

My code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var curDate = "2001-01-01";
        var URL = @"http://api.fixer.io/" + curDate + "?base=USD";
        Console.WriteLine(URL);
        //WebRequest wrGetURL = WebRequest.Create(URL);
        var text = "";
        //wrGetURL.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;

        using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (httpWebResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                    httpWebResponse.StatusCode, httpWebResponse.StatusDescription));
            }

            Stream stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

            DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JSONRead));
            JSONRead objResponse = (JSONRead)dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);

            Console.WriteLine(objResponse.rates.AUD);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class JSONRead
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "date")]
        public string date { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "rates")]
        public Rates rates { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "base")]
        public string bases { get; set; }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Rates
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "AUD")]
        public string AUD { get; set; }

        //[DataMember(Name = "key")]
        //public string key { get; set; }

        //[DataMember(Name = "value")]
        //public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

What I am trying to return:

```
Date        Code  Rate
2016-07-12  AUD   1.3101
2016-07-12  GBN   1.7633
etc...
```

Comment: Define rates as a Dictionary

Comment: @Plutonix forgive the ignorance but how would that look in code?  I saw other examples using Lists but that didn't return anything from the API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` and set `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` to `true`.  It then reads the nested object into a Dictionary object properly.  Thanks for the help @Plutonix.